# ASP.NET 4.7.2 OWIN JWT Bearer Authentication Bearer prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

The problem is that my ASP.NET Owin Bearer token authentication will not work if the header is implemented according to spec, so in the authorization header: "Bearer ey........". It only works if the token is directly sent, in the format: "ey....". When I use Bearer according to spec if the JwtTokenHandler is calling the method CanReadToken(string token) it will return false.

I would like to be able to use a Bearer token according to the specification, in the "Bearer ey..." format.

I am using all the latest NuGet packages:
Microsoft.Owin - 4.1.1
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin - 5.2.7
Owin - 1.0.0

This is my startup.cs code:

```
        // Get openid configuration to validate bearer tokens
        var openIdConfigManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        var openIdConfig = openIdConfigManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        // Clear defaultinboundclaimtypemaps 
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        // Add bearer token authentication
        var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenAudience"];
        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenIssuer"];

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAudiences = new List<string> { $"api://{audience}" },
                ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{issuer}/",
                IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys,
                RoleClaimType = "roles"
            },
            TokenHandler = new RemoveLeadingBearerJwtTokenHandler()
        });
```

I have a simple `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller.

I have tried the AuthenticationType setting, to set it to for example "ExternalBearer". I've tried setting the Realm to "Bearer".

The only thing that works for me is creating a custom JwtTokenHandler that removes the "Bearer " prefix and setting that as the TokenHandler. However this solution is not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I am embarrassed but to prevent any further embarrassment for others; the issue was that if you use the Bearer authentication option to Postman, the "Bearer " part is automatically added. You can check this by manually adding the Authentication Header.